# Python code: I want to multiply 2 columns that are in two different excel file and create a third excel file with the result of this multiplication

Tags: python, excel

I want create a python code. I have 2 excel file with the same structure. I need to create a python code that does the multiplication of each cell of the first excel file (one by one) for the cells of the second excel file. The results need to be on a third new excel file created by the code. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes. You could read your 2 excel sheets in as pandas dataframes (df1 and df2), create a new dataframe (df3) by multiplying the two together and export that to a new excel file

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this to get you started? It reads in two Excel files, does the multiplication and saves back to a new excel file.

```py
import pandas as pd

df_1 = pd.read_excel("path/to/file.xlsx")
df_2 = pd.read_excel("path/to/file2.xlsx")

df_3 = df_1 * df_2

df_3.to_excel("path/to/new/filename.xlsx")
```

Comment: fixed `import` was previously autocorrected to `Import`